# Angular 7 Http delete api handle body?

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I'm trying to talk to a somewhat REST API from an Angular 7 front end.

To remove some item from a collection, I need to send some other data in addition to the remove unique id, namely an authentication token, some collection info and some ancillary data.

However, the Http module of Angular 7 doesn't quite approve of a DELETE request with a body, and trying to make this request.

Here is my api:

```
DELETE /user/verifications

body {
  "doc_type": "govt_id",
  "doc_id": "5beedd169db947867b710afd"
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

this will work for angular 6+, where http is your HttpClient

```
const options = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }),
      body: {
        name: 'ravi',
        id: 'ravi123'
      }
    }

    this.http.delete('http://localhost:8080/user', options).subscribe(s => {
      console.log(s);
    })
```

Comment: Didn't work for me on angular6. I had to use `this.http.request('delete', url, options)` instead

Comment: was it giving any errors when you used "this.http.delete" method

Comment: saying `body` is not a valid key within the 2nd parameter (options)

Comment: can you please add some code, like how you have implemented and what body is

Comment: Nothing particular, my service is already doing multiple other http calls, and I'm used to code http calls so nothing weird here. The `options` object had 2 attributes: `headers` which is `{ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }` and `body` which is `{ ts: xxx }`

Answer (score 6):

Using `http.delete` didn't work for me on angular6, nor angular9. I had to use `this.http.request('delete', url, options)` instead.
Also, Typescript seems to have some issue about typing the response, so I had to force the result type manually with the `map` operator:

```
const httpOptions: any = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
};
const uri = '/path/to/delete/api';

httpOptions.body = {
  prop1: value1,
  prop2: value2
  // ...
};

return this.http.request<string>('delete', uri, httpOptions).pipe(
  map((result: any) => result as string), // fix typescript typing
  tap((result: string) => {
    console.log('response from server:', result);
  }
);
```